# How to plot a netgraph directed plot with varying edge width based on networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, netgraph

I would like to set different edge width in a network visualization with [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph) based on a [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) network. How to do this?
I am using netgraph as, to my knowledge, this is the only graph package to show two separate arrows in between two nodes. My code so far (`pools` and `processes_weight` are both `dict`):

```
import networkx as nx
import netgraph

network = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# Add node for each pool
for pool in pools_weight.keys():
        network.add_node(pool, size = pools_weight[pool])
# For process between pools, add an edge
for pool in processes.keys():
    for to_pool in processes[pool].keys():
        network.add_edge(pool, to_pool, weight = process_weight[pool][to_pool])

    
# Get positions for the nodes in G
pos_ = pool_pos #nx.spring_layout(network)

netgraph.draw(network, pos_, node_size=50 ,node_color='w', edge_color='k', edge_width=10.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I set different edge width based on my networkx network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/blob/master/netgraph/_main.py) you can use the keyword argument `edge_width` and pass a dict keyed by the edges to have different edge weights for each edge. Here's the portion from the `draw_edges()` function documentation that gets called explicitly from the `draw` function.

```
edge_width : float or dict (source, key) : width (default 1.)
        Line width of edges.
        NOTE: Value is rescaled by BASE_EDGE_WIDTH (1e-2) to work well with layout routines in igraph and networkx.
```

So if you have an edge attribute named `weight` in your networkx graph `network`, you can change your call to `netgraph.draw` as follows:

```
netgraph.draw(network, pos_, node_size=50 ,node_color='w', edge_color='k',
edge_width={(u,v):weight for u,v,weight in network.edges(data='weight')})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I also include different sizes of the nodes?

Comment: You can pass a dictionary keyed by the nodes to the `node_size` keyword argument. The function documentation points to all the inner functions it uses `draw_edges`, `draw_nodes`, `draw_node_labels`, and `draw_edge_labels` and they explain the possible arguments you can use to modify your graph.